# Mouse and Keyboard Freeze

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, mouse, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 today and have had mouse problem since.

Symptoms: At some arbitrary point in time (frequency: 2-3 times per hour), the mouse and keyboard stops working for ever(may be).

I start System monitor, I found out network was shutdown just before mouse freeze.

Some time my keyboard keep typing one key.
For example:77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777.....(it keep typing for >20 sec)

I found out a script just solve the freeze problem:(I hit Powerbutton)

```
-----------------/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh------------------------
event=button[ /]power

action=/usr/sbin/fix_mouse.sh



-----------------/usr/sbin/fix_mouse.sh------------------------

rmmod psmouse

modprobe psmouse
```

Yesterday I install Ubuntu 10.04 FAILED also have mouse problem.
When I switch back to Windows XP. The network card is down. It kept connecting and disconnecting 1 time per sec.

---

CPU: **i5**

Motherboard: **ASUS P7P55D**

OS: **Windows XP + Ubuntu 10.10**

Video Card: **ATI 5770**

Mouse,Keyboard: **PS/2**

---

### Edit:

I bought USB keyboard/mouse, and it works nicely.

Comment: Hi,

I have the same problem.

Using USB mouse and keyboard doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: In a deleted answer, [shocker](http://askubuntu.com/users/11366/shocker) notes this page as a possible solution to the problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10487963#post10487963

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

OK after reading several other threads I found THIS !!!

"I was using a USB Mouse Connected to my PS2 Mouse Port thru an adapter.

Connect your mouse directly to a USB Port. Do not connect to the PS2 mouse port. "

I am doing this myself and have not had any lockups as of yet (3 Hrs).

Try this and see what results you get .

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem, though USB mouse still work, only keyboard and touchpad would locked. I found out it's because I press a key repeatedly. For example when I use down arrow to read long article and then it would locked and typed down arrow infinitely. Also when I play tetris-like game when I usually press w button repeatedly, at some point it would keep typing w infinitely.

The only fix I could do is by suspend the laptop. Instead of going suspended, it would automatically wake up and then everything is fine again.

Not sure why it happens and how to fix it permanently though

Comment: Thanks for your answer & welcome to AU. Just keep in mind that this question is closed, you might not be rewarded.