# How do I install Intel UHD graphics on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: drivers, graphics

A few weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my new laptop but some graphical things like opening apps are going really slow. I think Ubuntu did not install graphics drivers.

My laptop's GPU is Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (Geminilake 2x6)

Comment: IIRC Intel graphics are supported by Ubuntu out of the box. What is the output of `lshw -C video`?

Comment: Many people are experiencing lags and freezes in 19.10. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185491/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-and-lags-reguarly This could be related to swapping or the graphics driver. Does your cursor stop moving under cpu load?

Comment: no the cursor does not stop working or something but i was all going a little bit freezie and i was afraid that my drivers where damaged