# Gnome started to stutter after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, lenovo, performance, gpu-driver

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro notebook with 4 GB RAM, a high-DPI screen, Intel integrated graphics (Model 80AY000 but the motherboard was replaced for some lower model during a repair). It worked okay until recent upgrade. Now the UI stutter on every load spike, like when opening an app or even when switching between tabs in a browser.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I observed htop and iotop and they don't show anything suspicious, however, it might be because they are also freezed during those moments.

```
free -h
              razem       użyte       wolne    dzielone   buf/cache    dostępne
Pamięć:       3,8Gi       1,8Gi       363Mi       696Mi       1,6Gi       1,1Gi
Wymiana:       1,4Gi       293Mi       1,1Gi
```

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
razem 44
drwxr-xr-x 11 pein pein 4096 lis 18 18:53 .
drwx------  3 pein pein 4096 lis 20 20:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 pein pein 4096 lis 18 18:53 BingWallpaper@ineffable-gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 pein pein 4096 paź  6 23:39 bitcoin-markets@ottoallmendinger.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 pein pein 4096 lis 10 00:20 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxrwxr-x  5 pein pein 4096 paź  6 23:39 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x  3 pein pein 4096 cze 21 20:28 gtktitlebar@velitasali.github.io
drwxr-xr-x  5 pein pein 4096 kwi  9  2019 no-title-bar@franglais125.gmail.com
# ^^^ this one is turned off, btw
drwxr-xr-x  4 pein pein 4096 kwi  9  2019 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxr-x  2 pein pein 4096 kwi 20  2019 transparent-gnome-panel@ttomovcik.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 pein pein 4096 maj  1  2019 transparentnotification@ipaq3870
```

```
dmidecode -s bios-version
76CN38WW
```

```
cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=dd3720dd-0a04-4ebd-901e-277e402697e0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9AE5-4726  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /home/pein                                ext4    rw              0       0
# ^^^ sdb1 is a USB3.0 flash stick
```

Tried running LiveUSB 19.10. It seems to be working fine.

[image: SMART data of the disk]

Tried answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185491/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-and-lags-reguarly) (upgrading kernel to 5.4 RC8, removing `xserver-xorg-video-intel` or installing it in version from ~oibaf ppa) with no success.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the specific make/model #'s of your notebook. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it solves your stuttering problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 19.10 freezes and lags reguarly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185491/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-and-lags-reguarly)

Comment: Indeed, seems like the same problem, but the answers didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Pending answer...

You have BIOS version 76CN38WW. Your BIOS needs an update. Backup all of your important data first. Then go to https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-2-pro-lenovo/downloads/ds035004 and download and install BIOS version 76CN43WW. If the problem is solved, then you may be done.

"Stutters" can be caused by a faulty GNOME extension. Eliminate a GNOME extension problem by temporarily disabling ALL extensions that you see at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. If the problem goes away, then enable one extension at a time until the problem returns. The last enabled extension would be the problem.

"Stutters" can be caused by swap problems. [Your swap is too small](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F) for 4G RAM, and `vm.swappiness` parameter may need adjustment. Resize swap from 1.4G to 4G, and temporarily set `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`. We'll set it permanently later.

"Stutters" can be caused by hard disk drive problems. Edit your question and show us screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application `SMART Data` window (it may take more than one screenshot to show all of the data).

Comment: Neither of these helped, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pein There were 3 suggestions. Which ones did you try?

Comment: All. I updated BIOS (the installer broke my GRUB, but I've fixed that already, nevermind), disabled all extensions, set /swapfile to 4GB and swappiness to 80.

Comment: @Pein edit your question with screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data window. It may take 2 screenshots to get all of the data. Is your boot disk a HDD or SSD?

Comment: I think the big issue here is it happened with the upgrade to 19.10 which brings with it a new kernel in addition to new gnome software.

Comment: @Pein status please. I'm still looking for the SMART Data.

Comment: @heynnema added the screen and more things I have tried

Comment: @Pein thanks for your `Disks` screenshot, however, I don't know the language. Can you please upload it again in English. Thanks!

Comment: @Pein status please...