# My Ubuntu machine freezes

Tags: google-chrome, 19.10, restart

I recently installed ubuntu 19.10 on my work station mainly to work on ML related projects. The graphic card is Evga RTX 2080. 16 GB Ram. I am using a AMS Processor. The following are all the parts I am have picked up.[MyPCParts](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Baradwaj/saved/#view=Dr7tpg)

My issue is the system is freezing suddenly. The mouser and keyboard do not respond. I left the system like that for a couple of hours hoping it comes out of freeze. But no luck.

The only solution I found so far is keep on restarting. And I have to restart my entire work.

I use chrome (jupyter notebook). When restart and restore the chrome it freezes again within minutes.

But if I start the chrome fresh, it might take a while to freeze.

I tried Mozilla Firefox as well. But ran into similar situation.

Is there a way to find the root cause?

Thanks and regards.

Update:

- I tried the following comment and the screen. The system did not freeze so far but the screen is missing some pixels and they appear all over the place when I use the keyboard.

[Changing the NVidia Settings in the Ubuntu Additional Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189035/521930)

The following is the image where the screen is with pixels.
[image]

Comment: Read `man swapon` ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/swapon.8.html ). Can you create a `swapfile`? Read `man mkswap` ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en /man8/mkswap.8.html ). Read `man free` ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/free.1.html ).

Comment: What mainboard and CPU are you using? I had a similar issue I fixed by disabling "Automatic C-State Management" in the BIOS, but I think that is AMD-specific.

Comment: @Sebastian Apologies. I could not come back due to some personal issues. Yes, I am using a AMD Processor. I will try this Automatic C-State Management and see if this helps me.

Comment: @waltinator I will try creating a swapfile and share it here. Thanks a lot. My apologies for this delayed response.

Comment: @heynnema Can you please take a look at the above issue. After doing the update, it seems to work fine but I am finding these wierd pixels.

Comment: Some months later ... was it the C-State thing? Would you accept an answer? I'm struggling with the same and would appreciate finding answers ;)

Comment: @Giszmo Sorry. I did not find a solution to that. I removed the ram and the processor too and reset them again into the system. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Well, that sucks. For what it's worth, my system runs stable since I did the c-state change 2 days ago. Wish Linux would at least detect stuff like that and give the user actionable advice instead of letting the users run into this one by one :(

Comment: Please let me know if the system is stable still. We can confirm this as an answer.