# Ubuntu 19.10 freezing, requires hard shutdown

Tags: dell, freeze, 19.10, xps

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.10
**Kernel:** 5.3.0-26-generic
**Machine:** Dell 7590
**BIOS Information:** Version: 1.5.0, Release Date: 12/25/2019
**Gnome:** 3.34.2

**Description:** starting 15-1-2020, I was updating a script for OLED screen brightness, then made an update at 1:50AM required restart and bios ran update utility, a few hour later or less the machine started having random freeze that require hard shutdown. below you will find the `syslog` before and after for the last incidence happened on 19-1-2020 at 4:00PM. also checked `dmsg`, but didn't notice any errors(except usual stuff).

**Tried Solutions(no luck):**

1. Login using older kernel version.
2. Removing my script.
3. Reading log files(syslog, dmsg, apt) for any clues.
4. Searching for similar issues, found [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185491/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-and-lags-reguarly), but it's not the exact same issue.

**Update 1:**
I believe this issue is related to recent Ubuntu software center BIOS update, Because my BIOS release date is 25-12-2019. but [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=02p03&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-7590-laptop) site says current available BIOS is 14-1-2020. posted another [question][3] on how to check Ubuntu software center BIOS log.

**Update 2:**
A comment mentioned that the issue is happening with other users suspecting it is case by `kernel 5.3.0-26`. I checked and noticed that `kernel 5.3.0-26` was installed the day before my issue started on 14-1-2020.

**Update 3:**
A new kernel `5.3.0-29-generic` is available now on 28-1-2020, but the machine again froze.

**Update 4:** 
Found this [answer][4], but it seems a lag for a couple of seconds not whole syetem freeze.

**Update 5:** After a few updates the issue is now gone, will check the reason and add it. But it's not `BIOS` issue for sure maybe kernel, mine is version `5.3.0-40-generic` now.

**Update 6:** The issue remain as is, but it disappear when I am connected to thunderbolt 3 dock. anyway now I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 20.04 and it seems stable.

**Before:**

```
Jan 19 15:48:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1072]: <warn>  [1579434548.0947] dhcp6 (wlp59s0): request timed out
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1072]: <info>  [1579434548.0948] dhcp6 (wlp59s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1072]: <info>  [1579434548.0949] dhcp6 (wlp59s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1072]: <info>  [1579434548.0949] dhcp6 (wlp59s0): state changed timeout -> done
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 4982.110274] audit: type=1107 audit(1579434548.095:121): pid=1022 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.15" mask="receive" pid=2725 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1072 peer_label="unconfined"
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 4982.110274]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 4982.111785] audit: type=1107 audit(1579434548.095:122): pid=1022 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.15" mask="receive" pid=2725 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1072 peer_label="unconfined"
Jan 19 15:49:08 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 4982.111785]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jan 19 15:49:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:51:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed]
Jan 19 15:52:21 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24179:1:0119/155221.073380:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:21 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24179:1:0119/155221.073897:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:25 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24180:1:0119/155225.734820:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:25 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24180:1:0119/155225.735396:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:52:51 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155251.902780:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:51 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155251.903376:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:51 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155251.903932:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:51 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155251.904340:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:52:52 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Jan 19 15:52:53 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155253.028033:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:53:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:54:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:55:07 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155507.701222:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:55:07 mudi-XPS-15-7590 gnome-shell[2435]: [24226:1:0119/155507.701840:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Jan 19 15:55:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:57:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed]
Jan 19 15:58:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 15:59:14 mudi-XPS-15-7590 wpa_supplicant[1052]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-62 noise=9999 txrate=90000
Jan 19 15:59:30 mudi-XPS-15-7590 dbus-daemon[2153]: [session uid=1000 pid=2153] Activating service name='org.gnome.GConf' requested by ':1.247' (uid=1000 pid=25137 comm="/home/mudi/.local/share/popcorn-time/Popcorn-Time " label="unconfined")
Jan 19 15:59:30 mudi-XPS-15-7590 dbus-daemon[2153]: [session uid=1000 pid=2153] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.GConf'
Jan 19 15:59:36 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 19 16:01:01 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: Timeout was reached
Jan 19 16:01:02 mudi-XPS-15-7590 wpa_supplicant[1052]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-59 noise=9999 txrate=300000
Jan 19 16:02:26 mudi-XPS-15-7590 xdg-desktop-por[2373]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: Timeout was reached
```

**After:**

```
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-modules-load[441]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-modules-load[441]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12"
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-modules-load[441]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-modules-load[441]: Inserted module 'coretemp'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-tmpfiles[470]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-tmpfiles[470]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-tmpfiles[470]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 lvm[439]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" monitored
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-tmpfiles[470]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-tmpfiles[470]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-udevd[589]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for code, revision 23.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 1288.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1440.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 8268.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-26-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-013) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-26.28-generic 5.3.13)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep vt.handoff=7
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-characters, revision 367.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 110.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-udevd[597]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-udevd[597]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for telegram-desktop, revision 994.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000403fffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040400000-0x000000005bd23fff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005bd24000-0x000000005bd24fff] ACPI NVS
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-udevd[606]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005bd25000-0x000000005bd25fff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005bd26000-0x000000006b867fff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006b868000-0x000000006cfdffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006cfe0000-0x000000006d05cfff] ACPI data
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006d05d000-0x000000006d9d1fff] ACPI NVS
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for skype, revision 107.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006d9d2000-0x000000006fe21fff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006fe22000-0x000000006fffefff] type 20
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 1650.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006ffff000-0x000000006fffffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070000000-0x0000000077ffffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078000000-0x0000000078dfffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078e00000-0x000000007f7fffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 71.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Found device Force MP510 EFI\x20System\x20Partition.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000047c7fffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.70 by American Megatrends
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/D2DA-DEF2...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x6cff9000  ACPI=0x6cff9000  SMBIOS=0xf0000  SMBIOS 3.0=0xf0020  TPMFinalLog=0x6d910000  ESRT=0x6fa8b698  MEMATTR=0x68f6c018 
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: Dell Inc. XPS 15 7590/0VYV0G, BIOS 1.5.0 12/25/2019
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2600.000 MHz processor
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002584] tsc: Detected 2599.992 MHz TSC
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Created slice system-lvm2\x2dpvscan.slice.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002584] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002585] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002590] last_pfn = 0x47c800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 259:2...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002616] MTRR default type: write-back
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002617] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002617]   00000-9FFFF write-back
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002618]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002618]   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002619] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002619]   0 base 00C0000000 mask 7FC0000000 uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002620]   1 base 007C000000 mask 7FFC000000 uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002620]   2 base 007B000000 mask 7FFF000000 uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-fsck[878]: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002621]   3 base 00A0000000 mask 7FE0000000 uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002621]   4 base 0090000000 mask 7FF0000000 uncachable
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-fsck[878]: 0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002622]   5 base 0080000000 mask 7FF0000000 write-combining
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002622]   6 disabled
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002622]   7 disabled
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002623]   8 disabled
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-fsck[878]:  Automatically removing dirty bit.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002623]   9 disabled
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.002975] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.003116] last_pfn = 0x78e00 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008254] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000006fa8b698 to 0x000000006fa8b6d0.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-fsck[878]: Performing changes.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008260] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008263] Using GB pages for direct mapping
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008264] BRK [0x214201000, 0x214201fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008266] BRK [0x214202000, 0x214202fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008267] BRK [0x214203000, 0x214203fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-fsck[878]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 22 files, 12042/130812 clusters
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008303] BRK [0x214204000, 0x214204fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008304] BRK [0x214205000, 0x214205fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008452] BRK [0x214206000, 0x214206fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/D2DA-DEF2.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008486] BRK [0x214207000, 0x214207fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008589] BRK [0x214208000, 0x214208fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008641] BRK [0x214209000, 0x214209fff] PGTABLE
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008724] RAMDISK: [mem 0x31cdd000-0x34e65fff]
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008734] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008741] ACPI: RSDP 0x000000006CFF9000 000024 (v02 DELL  )
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008744] ACPI: XSDT 0x000000006CFF90C8 000114 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008747] ACPI: FACP 0x000000006D03A0A8 000114 (v06 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008750] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000006CFF9270 040E36 (v02 DELL   CBX3     01072009 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008752] ACPI: FACS 0x000000006D9D0C00 000040
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for shotcut, revision 58.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008754] ACPI: APIC 0x000000006D03A1C0 0000F4 (v04 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008755] ACPI: FPDT 0x000000006D03A2B8 000044 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008757] ACPI: FIDT 0x000000006D03A300 00009C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 lvm[879]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" now active
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008758] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000006D03A3A0 00003C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 MSFT 00000097)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008760] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D03A3E0 001B26 (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008761] ACPI: BOOT 0x000000006D03BF08 000028 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008763] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D03BF30 001663 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008765] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D03D598 002644 (v02 PegSsd PegSsdt  00001000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for code, revision 22.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008766] ACPI: HPET 0x000000006D03FBE0 000038 (v01 DELL\x CBX3     00000002      01000013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008768] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D03FC18 001441 (v02 DELL\x CflH_Tbt 00001000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008769] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000006D041060 000042 (v01 DELL\x CBX3     00000002      01000013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008771] ACPI: LPIT 0x000000006D0410A8 000094 (v01 DELL\x CBX3     00000002      01000013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008772] ACPI: WSMT 0x000000006D041140 000028 (v01 DELL   CBX3     00000002      01000013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-logs, revision 81.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008774] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D041168 0027DE (v02 DELL\x PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008775] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000006D043948 00037A (v02 DELL\x TbtTypeC 00000000 INTL 20160527)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 kernel: [    0.008777] ACPI: DBGP 0x000000006D043CC8 000034 (v01 DELL\x CBX3     00000002      01000013)
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for shotcut, revision 59.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-calculator, revision 544.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-calculator, revision 501.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for skype, revision 109.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Jan 19 16:34:28 mudi-XPS-15-7590 systemd-udevd[691]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
```

Comment: Maybe helpfull https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/issues/215

Comment: @nobody. First of all, thanks for your help. Second, I suspected the issue to be related to this error message, and I did some search and found people saying it's not a harmful message, also I checked my logs to found that it has been there forever. I will try fixing it anyway of course, but the machine keeps freezing right now every like a few minutes.

Comment: I use Linux Mint and started having random freezes as of today, three already. My colleague next door uses Ubuntu, but has the same problems (only starting today), we suspect the kernel 5.3.0-26

Comment: Hi @Sentry, thanks so much for your comment. I checked and noticed that kernel 5.3.0-26 was installed the day before. So I think you maybe right. will update the post accordingly.