# How to check Ubuntu Software center BIOS update logs?

Tags: dell, software-center, bios, xps

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.10
**Kernel:** 5.3.0-26-generic
**Machine:** Dell 7590
**BIOS Information:** Version: 1.5.0, Release Date: 12/25/2019

**Description:** I am facing an [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204179/ubuntu-19-10-freezing-requires-hard-shutdown) with my laptop, and I think it is related to recent BIOS update done by Ubuntu software center on 14-1-2020. but I didn't restart my machine until 15-1-2020(when the issue started happening). as you can see BIOS release date is 25-12-2019. but [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=02p03&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-7590-laptop) site says current available BIOS is 14-1-2020.

**My question is:** How to check for last BIOS update log, or Ubuntu software center log?

Comment: In your log files do you have an fwupd.log? In /var/log?

Comment: @oldfred no log file with that name in /var/log

Comment: Generally best to have latest UEFI and if SSD latest firmware for SSD. Dell XPS 15 Series 7590 (2019)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590 & 
https://github.com/TillmannBerg/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019
 & https://github.com/fwupd/fwupdhttps://github.com/fwupd/fwupd & https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @oldfred, thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it. But yes I know these issues, actually I made a [script](https://github.com/MuDiAhmed/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019) myself to fix them. But my issue recently appeared and I believe it's BIOS related, but I am not sure how to check for BIOS update logs or BIOS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to view BIOS logs was in the BIOS itself. Enter the `BIOS` (hit F2 on Dell startup screen), then `System Logs`, then `BIOS events` section. On my Dell laptop, this update shows up as "Firmware update is successful" within the BIOS events. I'm assuming any errors would appear in this events list.

For what it is worth, my installed Dell 1.5.0 BIOS update is also dated 12/25/2019. Hope that helps.