# Buzzing sound when scrolling on Dell XPS 9350 and Ubuntu kernel 5.5

Tags: kernel, dell

I've had some troubles with lagging on my Dell XPS 9350 and Ubuntu Kernel 5.3 - see also related issue: [Ubuntu 19.10 freezes and lags reguarly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185491/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-and-lags-reguarly)

So I switched to kernel 5.5 and there are improvements, however there is a quiet but still buzzing sound coming out of the laptop, when scrolling, e.g. through a file. Not always, but when I use PhpStorm, which is an IDE, that is more resource-intensive.

If I switch back to an older kernel (everything below 5.5) this sound completely goes away.

Any ideas?

Edit (2020-02-28): I just made tests with (atm latest) kernel versions 5.5.6 and 5.6.0-rc3 and had same issue.

Comment: Same happens to me using Fedora. Kernel `vmlinuz-5.4.17-100.fc30.x86_64` works flawlessly, while `vmlinuz-5.5.6-100.fc30.x86_64` produces an awful coil whine.

Comment: Same here. Do you have any, even any, hint about why this happens?

Comment: I've tried the newest 5.5.* version when it came out, but the issue still persist and I had to go back to 5.4. I'm using Fedora, but it has nothing to do with the distribution - clearly, it's something related to the Linux kernel. Has anyone tried using 5.6 kernel version?  If that's still the case, I suppose we have to address this in some way (file a bug report somewhere).

Comment: I filed a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207543