# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes

Tags: 19.10

Since I switched to Ubuntu 19.10, I've been having untimely freezes. Some of them last a few seconds (between 2 and 5 seconds) but others completely block the computer and my only solution is to use the [magic keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) or to force the shutdown via the shutdown button.

[I saw that it could be a kernel regression](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189566/959170), nevertheless the proposed solutions were applied, without success.

Are there solutions to this problem?

Information:

```
Vendor: Lenovo
Model: Legion Y540-15IRH
Linux: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64
```

Update:

As recommended by [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733), I looked in `/var/log/syslog` at a time close to the freeze and this is what I found:

```
Feb 26 22:07:19 mrsquaare-Legion-Y540-15IRH systemd-udevd[425]: Worker [4654] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
Feb 26 22:07:19 mrsquaare-Legion-Y540-15IRH systemd-udevd[425]: 0000:01:00.3: Worker [4654] failed
Feb 26 22:07:19 mrsquaare-Legion-Y540-15IRH kernel: [ 1225.182894] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffae87c02ad000
Feb 26 22:07:19 mrsquaare-Legion-Y540-15IRH kernel: [ 1225.182901] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Feb 26 22:07:19 mrsquaare-Legion-Y540-15IRH kernel: [ 1225.182904] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[...]
```

[See complete logs](https://pastebin.com/8T1hHipY)

I also redirected `dmesg -w` to a file before the crash, which also reports the same problem.

Comment: Check /var/crash for .crash files that match the time of a freeze-requiring-reboot. Check `top` and `free` for unusual disk or CPU activity. Note the exact time of a short freeze and look in /var/log/syslog at that time for error messages and other clues.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for your response, I updated the post. And unfortunately I don't have any files in `/var/crash`.

Comment: Take the entire log section starting with `BUG: unable to handle page fault for address` and ending when you began to reboot, copy it into a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com), and put the link in your question.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the advice, I've updated the post.

Comment: Test to see if the problem occurs using a 20.04 LiveUSB in the "Try Ubuntu" environment. If so, please file a bug report against the `linux` package: `ubuntu-bug linux`. Add your log to the bug report. That's all you can really do for the freeze-requiring-reboot -- the kernel crashed hard. Possible GPU issue, possibly not -- I'm not expert at deciphering stacktraces.