# What nVidia Driver for RTX 2080 in Ubuntu 19.10 to solve system freeze and pixel problems?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I have been working on fixing the issue of Ubuntu freeze. All of a sudden the system freezes and I had to restart it. I have followed a solution posted on the [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1192994/521930). According to this I selected the Nvidia driver package as follows.

[image]

The actual option was the 3rd. I selected the first one and since then the system never froze till now. But I am seeing some pixels on the screen which are out of place. And this is happening quite often but there was no freeze at all.

The following is the image of the out of order pixels on the home page.

[image]

Could some one help me with the fixing the pixel problem? Should I install some other display driver?

Comment: This is the third time that you've asked this exact same question. My last comment on your other question was... "For your Samsung SSD, in Windows, download the "Samsung Magician" software, and check the firmware of the SSD. Regarding the Nvidia drivers, yes, they can be a pain. Switch to the nouveau driver, then do `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and then `sudo apt-get purge packagename` to remove all of the Nvidia stuff, and retry 440. Report back.".

Comment: @heynnema Sure. I will work on it and get back to you as soon as possible. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @heynnema I have not tried it but so far. I am running some scripts on the machine. But yeah this is the current one problem I am facing. Minor but would love to resolve it and get back to you.